# App different package name but same signing key?

Tags: android, package, code-signing-certificate

My android app has same signing key but different package name does it give any impact on my existing app, I want to know once i publish it , it will install as an update or as a complete new app ?

Because i want to update my app!

Answer (score 2):

No impact.

Package manager use package name to identify each apk.

Signing key are used only during update process for check is apk will be replaced by the apk from the same developer or not.

Edit (due to question was edited):

1. You can't update your application if new APK has different package name.
2. You can have two applications signed by the same key installed on the same device.

Comment: It is always better to use different key to sign apps with different package name. It is followed as best practice even though it has no impact.

Comment: @AmrutBidri  it impacts.(Package name changed) Your app wont be treated as updated version instead it will be installed as new app or asks user to uninstall the previous one.

Comment: @MaxV Once you change the package name it will not be treated as a Updated version of your previous app. So it impacts!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create a different signing key for new package name but you can add another application with same signing key. This will be treated as a new application.